# error 0x80004005 whilst building C# class lib as part of windows forms app

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, azure-devops, building

I've a solution containing several projects. One of these projects, that I use for most of my application resources, is failing to build. I think it's usually in release mode rather than debug, but it may be when I change platform target between all cpus and x86. Sorry if I'm being vague but sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Sometimes it works after switching modes then restarting visual studio 2010.
I always run Visual Studio 2010 in administrator mode. I removed any read-only flags from all the files in the project.
I pulled the project out of my main solution and added it to an empty windows forms application for test purposes and it does the same thing there.
0x80004005 is a permissions error.
I don't know why this just started happening. The app has been working ok for years until I added it to Team Foundation (web version) and it stopped since.
Anybody able to help please as I'm trying to get the damn thing built and delivered?

```
Error   1   The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode, Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Close()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, IResourceWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() pulse.smartcentre.resources
```

Comment: 0x80004005 is not a permissions error.  It is E_FAIL, "Unknown error".  Can be anything, .NET just reports it as "A generic error occurred".  The most common explanation is that there's something wrong with the image data.  You ought to try replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of your stack trace, where it says "interop, etc", and from the look of the error code, it's definitely the COM object that is responsible for the actual write eventually, that is failing.

In the "causes" paragraph of this, note the 2nd and 3rd bullets:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306269

it may sometimes be not about permissions, but about locks, seemingly (likely by another process, maybe related to TFS).

To find that sort of culprit, I used a few times this bro, with success:

http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

(It'll help you spy on pretty much "everything" that is running at any point, be it Win32 or .NET, down to every opened file handle, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I took the whole project out of TFS, took the read only attribute off all files and now it compiles ok.